# Filter collection by child

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have the following fictional object which I'm trying to filter:

```
{  
    "0":{  
        "boy":{  
            "age":"32",
            "name":"Daniel Grey"
        }
     },
     "1":{  
        "boy":{  
            "age":"23",
            "name":"John Doe"
         }
     }
}
```

And then, the ng-repeat directive looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">{{person.boy.name}}<li>
</ul>
```

My question is, how do I filter people by "name"? I've tried:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:name">{{person.boy.name}}<li>
</ul>
```

... but nothing happens [ ng-model seems disconnected from the view! ].

Any response is much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7cnocmpr/1/

Comment: `people` is not a valid JSON object btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updated answer as per OP's updates***

Looking at your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apwwy84s/2/), your `$scope.people` is essentially an array with one big JSON object, with multiple nested `boy` objects. This is hard to work with. If you have control over the construction of the JSON object, I will suggest converting into an array of multiple JSON objects, which may look something like:

```
$scope.people = [
    {
        "name":"Daniel Grey",
        "age":"32",
        "gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "name":"John Doe",
        "age":"23",
        "gender": "male"
    }
];
```

Notice how I converted the `boy` key into the `gender` attribute.

If you really have absolutely no control over the data structure, you may have to come up with a custom filter to parse through the nested structure.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/apwwy84s/). A few things to pay attention to:

1. I have to specify `people[0]` in `ng-repeat` to retrieve the one big JSON object in your array.
2. The custom `nameFilter` searches the `.boy.name` attribute only.

***Original Answer***

If you want your filter by **just** name, you will have to specify the specific attributes in your `ng-model` directive. So in your case, it will be

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.boy.name">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search">{{person.boy.name}}<li>
</ul>
```

But first you will need to fix your `JSON` object.

UPDATE:

Live demo on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/apwwy84s/). I did notice that the search-by-name-only filter doesn't work with angularjs 1.2.1, but works with angularjs 1.2.2.

Comment: I've updated the JSON object with the actual structure in my app. The question still remains: how do I filter by "name"?

Comment: @AlexandruPopovici I have added a fiddle to my answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: thank you very much in your effort to help me. You are very kind and I appreciated. I've seen your fiddle and, indeed, it works. However, at a second look to my JSON object, this is a bit different. I've updated the first post with the new structure, which you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/apwwy84s/2/ . And one additional note: I'm using angularjs v.1.3

Comment: @AlexandruPopovici The `"0"`, `"1"` etc. indices are tricky. Do you have control over how the JSON object is constructed. If yes, you can convert it into an array, and change the `boy` key to say `gender: 'male'`.

Comment: @AlexandruPopovici Otherwise, we might have to try coming up with a custom directive.

Comment: I've created the exact structure of my JSON, controller and HTML here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/0exevoeu/1/ Can you please have a look?

Comment: @AlexandruPopovici This your JSON structure is missing a bracket. Anyway, I manage to parse the JSON structure using nested `ng-repeat` and filter the data by name using a custom filter. Take a look at this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ivan_sim/yctchgnk/)

Comment: @AlexandruPopovici You're welcome. Can I get you to upvote the answer too, so it's easier for others to find in the future? Thanks!